# Unique Id for a page fed to a user in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, uniqueidentifier

In my ASP.NET MVC 3 site I need to have ajax retrieve some `ActionResult`s data asyncronously after the page has been sent to a user browser.

To differentiate between pages I need each page to be "equipped" with a unique identifier, that js code has access to an is able to provide as a "pass" to some action calls.

I can generate this identifier as a System.Guid on my Index action that returns the view. I can assign it to a ViewBag and save to my data storage for upcoming usage. To what should I render it on the page, to allow my js code to access it? A hidden input would suffice? How do I implement this setting in Razor markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HiddenFor HTML helper which will render a hidden input

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PageId)
```

You can access this in your javascript code before making the ajax call.

```
  var pageId=$("#PageId").val();
  $.post("mycontroller/action"+pageId,function(data)
   {
        //do whatever with response.
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

A hidden input would be perfect:

```
<input type="hidden" name="pageId" value="@Model.PageId" />
```